# What is this early 3D platformer?

Tags: ibm-pc, identify-this-game

**Video:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_-fcFivTS8&t=599s

**Image:**
[image: image of gameplay from linked clip]

I'm having a hard time tracking down a game I played when I was a kid. It was on DOS in the early 90s. It had flat-shaded polygon graphics--cutting-edge for their time, and you played as some kind of abstract lamp-shaped robot and you had to navigate a maze of large cubic rooms. Each room had a bunch of small floating platforms, and most of them made you bounce.

The linked video has about 10s of footage from it used as stock. The screen distortions aren't part of the game but this is the only footage I've managed to find in the past almost 30 years...

Comment: Would an embedded screen shot including the game be good to have here in case the YouTube video gets removed in the future?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is a very early 3D DOS exploration game from 1990 called ***Alpha Waves***, also released as ***Continuum***.

Also available on the Atari ST and Amiga.